# Vimeo embed on Android HTML5 + Phonegap + jQueryMobile App

Tags: android, html, iframe, cordova, vimeo

I'm developing an *html5 + JqueryMobile + Phonegap* app. I embed some Vimeo's video in iframe with the code below. It works fine in iOS devece. But when I test on Android Device, I can see only the video's thumbnail with the play button. When I click the play button the spin rotate for few second and then come back the play button.

Any suggestion? I need to play the video also in external player (But it's important that when the video ends I can close the player and come back to the app)

```
<iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67500201?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="color:transparent; height:181px; position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling against the same problem. I found this http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:103961 that gives us the answer: looks like not every android platform is supported ATM :(